# Paper.js eraser tool made using layers and blendMode

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, paperjs, drawing2d

I am making simple drawing app using Paper.js and Node.js. There are 2 layers:
- bottom layer with images
- top layer for drawing. 
Layer with images is background to drawing layer.

I want to make a simple eraser tool which will erase drawing on a path. I'm trying to do it adding second path in my top layer which has blendMode set to "destination-out".

```
drawingLayer.activate();
path = new Path();
path.strokeColor = 'black';
path.strokeWidth = 5;

if (mode == "erase") {
  path.strokeWidth = 15;
  path.blendMode = 'destination-out';
}
```

My problem is that this "destination-out" path erases not only everything on top layer (drawing layer) but also everything on the bottom layer (images). Of course I want images to stay untouched by eraser. When I set some background in css for my page it is not erased by the eraser path.

Do you know a way to make eraser to modify one top layer while not modyfing bottom layer?

Comment: How did you end up implementing this feature? I find that even using destination-out on the top layer leaves a white mark over the bottom layer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to activate the layer you want to erase in just before using the eraser tool, like this:

```
var firstLayer = paper.project.activeLayer; //This one is used to erase
var shapesLayer = new Layer(); // We don't want to erase on this one
```

so basically, when eraser tool is selected I do

```
firstLayer.activate();
```

Then when I want to draw shapes just activate the 'shapesLayer' the same way. This avoids the tool (the one used for erasing) touch anything from 'shapesLayer'

Comment: If I understand correctly, your images (or you mention shapes, different to what the OP asks) then reside on the top layer - don't they obscure the paths on the bottom layer?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you have to encapsulate your drawings items and your eraser items into a group which has the blend mode `source-over`.
This way, the background items won't be affected by the eraser items `destination-out` blend mode.
Here's a simple [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.7/S/pZJBSwMxEIX/ypDLKm7LKnhZ6akHT4LgcbuHbDLtho0zZZK0h9L/bpbVUkWxaGAIbx4hX97koEi/oqrVy4DR9KpUhu2oDVOI0GkzbIQT2aUT4xEWQLiHZx37+dS5OqxkRZCXQYooNewc7ueTKD880dalUMN9dWqtnfdL9pxPFCyaNliM1vH6YdzGmhDWLPgPBLiBu+pSjs6nHyhQdED5K0FzW5VQtZdj5NiLk9V5JPuUx5ItiyE60tExzTjF3yJ7R33MYnsG2TtvBamG5mu65aeXtt8wFIGTGJzxDuX8+vx1OkE9bNlRDKpu2uMb) demonstrating this.

```js
const backgroundCircle = new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center,
    radius: 50,
    fillColor: 'orange'
});

const foregroundCircle = new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center + 20,
    radius: 50,
    fillColor: 'blue'
});

const eraserCircle = new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center + [10, 0],
    radius: 50,
    fillColor: 'black',
    blendMode: 'destination-out'
});

const foreground = new Group({
    children: [foregroundCircle, eraserCircle],
    blendMode:'source-over'
});
```